# how to choose PDF file in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, pdf

I searched online and GitHub and couldn't find a way to properly select a PDF in IOS like with an image or video. For example, I can open and select a photo (select the photo with other methods that hadle it) like this:

```
self.logoImagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
self.logoImagePicker.delegate = self;
[self.logoImagePicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
[self presentViewController:self.logoImagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I've attempted this:

```
// Present PDF;s from which to choose
UIDocumentInteractionController *pdfPicker = [[UIDocumentInteractionController alloc] init];
pdfPicker.delegate = self; // ensure you set the delegate so when a PDF is chosen the right method can be called

[self presentViewController:pdfPicker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

But i get an error here:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
@autoreleasepool {
    return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil,     NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
}
}
```

With this error output:

```
2016-08-10 07:40:59.190 Whats New[55195:1962738] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'No available types for source 0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00ef1494 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0060fe02 objc_exception_throw + 50
2   UIKit                               0x01eb9dc2 -[UIImagePickerController mediaTypes] + 0
3   Whats New                           0x000c6253 -[SellerHomePageViewController choosePdfBtn:] + 243
4   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x006240b5 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 84
5   UIKit                               0x01ab0e38 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 118
6   UIKit                               0x01ab0db7 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 64
7   UIKit                               0x01c54f3b -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 79
8   UIKit                               0x01c552d4 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 433
9   UIKit                               0x01c542c1 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 714
10  UIKit                               0x02037d2e _UIGestureRecognizerUpdate + 12763
11  UIKit                               0x01b30efd -[UIWindow _sendGesturesForEvent:] + 1559
12  UIKit                               0x01b325b6 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 1137
13  UIKit                               0x01ad3be8 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 266
14  UIKit                               0x01aa8769 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 7795
15  CoreFoundation                      0x00e03e5f __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
16  CoreFoundation                      0x00df9aeb __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 523
17  CoreFoundation                      0x00df8f08 __CFRunLoopRun + 1032
18  CoreFoundation                      0x00df8846 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
19  CoreFoundation                      0x00df865b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
20  GraphicsServices                    0x05aa5664 GSEventRunModal + 192
21  GraphicsServices                    0x05aa54a1 GSEventRun + 104
22  UIKit                               0x01aaeeb9 UIApplicationMain + 160
23  Whats New                           0x000d1e4a main + 138
24  libdyld.dylib                       0x03cc4a25 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Is there something similar to choosing photos but only for PDF's?

Comment: And where are supposed to be the .pdf files? And why should they be available with `UIImagePickerController`?

Comment: I apologize, pasted the wrong thing

Comment: You should call `+interactionControllerWithURL:`, not the `alloc`/`init`.

Comment: i am not trying to load a predetermined PDF file, i need the user to select a pdf on their phone to upload later

Comment: There is no "Finder.app" or "Explorer.exe" in iOS. Apps are sandboxes. From where is coming the "pool of .pdf"? Where are they stored? There is no API for that. `UIDocumentInteractionController` is only use to do an "Open with". Check the UI associated to it (Google Images gives what it looks like).

Comment: wow, that sucks, on Android, it was a simple `intent` which would open a document view and show only PDF's. Thanks Apple

Answer (score 0):

1- There is no native control for like UIImagePicker that lets you pick a PDF.

2- You have no access to PDFs in the iphone since unlike android, there is no Explorer.

If you want to save PDFs you should save them as coreData in your app, and you should make a UITableView or UICOllectionView with a view for each PDF as a PDF Picker. Keep in mind this will stay within the context of the app as IOS behaves differently than android

Comment: is there a GitHub that enables an Explorer?

Comment: glad i helped you out! can you mark this as the correct answer so this thread can be closed please :)

Comment: before i do, can i populate a table view with the PDF's on the phone?

Comment: no, because you cant access pdfs outise your app. you can store pdfs in you app and save them. and show them in a uitableview. what are you trying to achieve exactly? maybe I can help you out

Comment: I want to upload a PDF to my server but i cannot access the PDF's on the Iphone

Comment: so dumb, dont know why apple disable that

Comment: Whatsapp allows you to choose different types of documents (including PDFs) from local storage and iCloud, so this should be possible.